# undefined method `relative_url_root=' for ActionController::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically trying to start learning RoR and have tried to set it up on my VPS running nginx and unicorn. I wanted to install it into a subdirectory so it seems like my nginx is setup properly. However, I tried adding `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/rails'` to my config/environments/production.rb and it gives me an undefined method. What else can I do to check? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3.X this option no longer exists. It's possible to achieve a similar result using [scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/scope) within routes definition. So you can do something like the following:

```
scope "/rails" do
   resources :posts
   root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

Comment: How else would someone deploy a Rails app under a sub directory?

Comment: yeah, I don't think that does the same thing at all. How do you deploy a rails app under a sub-path, not at /, on a web server? Somehow passenger _does_ it, but if you were rolling your own and not using passenger, how would you do it?

Comment: @lucapette  it seems like `scope` is available only in rails 3.x+ what is the equivalent of that for rails 2.3 ?